# How to make a related field mandatory in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, relationship

Suppose I have the following many-to-one relationship in Django:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    # ...

class Address(models.Model):
    # ...
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This allows a person to have multiple addresses.

I wish to make it mandatory for a person to have at least one address, so it will be impossible to save a person with no addresses in the DB.

How can I achieve this goal? Is it possible to make a related field mandatory (as can be done for "normal" fields using `blank=False`)?

Answer (score 2):

As previously said, there's no way to enforce a relationship directly on the database.

However, you can take care of it by validating the model before saving using the `clean()` method. It will be automatically triggered on save for Django models.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    .
    .
    .
    def clean(self):
        if len(self.addresses) == 0:
            raise ValidationError('At least one address is required.')
```

Comment: According to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean), you must call .clean() yourself as it is not automatically triggered on save: `Note, however, that like Model.full_clean(), a model’s clean() method is not invoked when you call your model’s save() method.`

Answer (score 0):

Why not make Address a many to many relationship on Person? That seems to be a more natural expression of your data.

But regardless, you can't really enforce the many to many realation on the db. You could perhaps override the save of Person to check for an address. But I would prefer to handle it in the form logic.